# How to register instance seveal times with the same key in UnityContainer

Tags: c#, unity-container

I would like to let the system keep one and only one copy of instance with some special key in UnityContainer. And I also want to have the ability to override/update that key with other instances. The following code shows my first thought:

```
 var UnityContainer = new UnityContainer();
 for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
 {
     Person p = new Person();
     UnityContainer.RegisterInstance<Person>("Person", p);
 }
```

However, the above code has memory leak issue. 100 copies of Person instance will be referenced by the UnityContainer, and couldn't be recycle. What I want is only keep the latest instance of Person in memory.
Change it to the following code could not resolve the problem. Because, now all instances of Person were keep in UnityContainer by using weak reference, which means all instance of Person could be recycle if there is no other place keep reference with them.

```
UnityContainer.RegisterInstance<Person>("Person", p, new ExternallyControlledLifetimeManager());
```

The funny thing is that it returns 'True' when I call UnityContainer.IsRegistered("Person"). However, if I call UnityContainer.Resolve("Person"), the system will throw exception. So I couldn't use the UnityContainer.IsRegistered method to decide whether an available instance existing there or not.

Comment: What you do sounds an awful lot like your are trying to use the container as a cache. Why do you want to do what you are trying to do?

Comment: Did you actually measure memory leaks here? I'm a little surprised - the container shouldn't be holding onto the lifetime manager after you've overwritten the registration.

Comment: Also, IsRegistered is exactly that - has this type/name been registered with the container. Not CanResolve, not HasAnInstance, just IsRegistered.

Comment: @Chris Tavares Yes, there is a potential memory issue. I have traced it by WinDbg. There are 100 instances of Person and ContainerControlledLifetimeManager. the person is referenced by the ContainerControlledLifetimeManager, which is referenced by UnityContainer. What i am curious is when use the same key to reister instance why the Unity doesn't dispose the existing LifetimeManager or remove the Person's reference from LifetimeManager. And why the Unity doesn't provide the UnRegisterInstance method.

Comment: @Sebastian Weber  May I know the reason why can't I do this way? I think it is straightforward, since the Unity allows us register a type more than once using the RegisterInstance method.

Comment: A DI container is not a cache. The correct [usage pattern is register-resolve-release](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/09/29/TheRegisterResolveReleasePattern.aspx). You register **all** dependencies in one go at one place called [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx). You resolve the root object of your application and when you are done you tell the container to release this object. If you need something that behaves like a cache, use a cache.

Comment: I looked in the code and see the source of the memory leak. It's just a bug - the container keeps a list of all the things it should dispose in a separate data structure. When you reregister with the same type/name pair, the lifetime manager is overwritten but the pointer from the lifetime container (list of stuff to dispose) is not removed. As for the lack of Unregister, there's no real use case for it - you're not really using the container in the intended manner if you want that.